# MySQL InnoDB Row limit with TEXT columns

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an Aurora MySQL 5.6 instance where I am trying to create a table with about 200 TEXT columns and a few others. I am receiving the infamous error "Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline." But according to my calculations, my table should be using way less than that. TEXT fields only need 20 bytes each according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html#innodb-row-format-dynamic so I can't see why I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

Here's the statement:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS danstest ( entry_id bigint(20) not null,
 date_created timestamp(3),
 date_modified timestamp(3),
 created_by bigint(20),
 modified_by bigint(20),
 container_id bigint(20),
 archived bit(1) not null default 0,
 `geometry` GEOMETRY,
 owner bigint(20),
 mode tinyint(1) default 0,
field_0 TEXT comment 'Column 1',
field_1 TEXT comment 'Column 2',
field_2 TEXT comment 'Column 3',
field_3 TEXT comment 'Column 4',
field_4 TEXT comment 'Column 5',
field_5 TEXT comment 'Column 6',
field_6 TEXT comment 'Column 7',
field_7 TEXT comment 'Column 8',
field_8 TEXT comment 'Column 9',
field_9 TEXT comment 'Column 10',
field_10 TEXT comment 'Column 11',
field_11 TEXT comment 'Column 12',
field_12 TEXT comment 'Column 13',
field_13 TEXT comment 'Column 14',
field_14 TEXT comment 'Column 15',
field_15 TEXT comment 'Column 16',
field_16 TEXT comment 'Column 17',
field_17 TEXT comment 'Column 18',
field_18 TEXT comment 'Column 19',
field_19 TEXT comment 'Column 20',
field_20 TEXT comment 'Column 21',
field_21 TEXT comment 'Column 22',
field_22 TEXT comment 'Column 23',
field_23 TEXT comment 'Column 24',
field_24 TEXT comment 'Column 25',
field_25 TEXT comment 'Column 26',
field_26 TEXT comment 'Column 27',
field_27 TEXT comment 'Column 28',
field_28 TEXT comment 'Column 29',
field_29 TEXT comment 'Column 30',
field_30 TEXT comment 'Column 31',
field_31 TEXT comment 'Column 32',
field_32 TEXT comment 'Column 33',
field_33 TEXT comment 'Column 34',
field_34 TEXT comment 'Column 35',
field_35 TEXT comment 'Column 36',
field_36 TEXT comment 'Column 37',
field_37 TEXT comment 'Column 38',
field_38 TEXT comment 'Column 39',
field_39 TEXT comment 'Column 40',
field_40 TEXT comment 'Column 41',
field_41 TEXT comment 'Column 42',
field_42 TEXT comment 'Column 43',
field_43 TEXT comment 'Column 44',
field_44 TEXT comment 'Column 45',
field_45 TEXT comment 'Column 46',
field_46 TEXT comment 'Column 47',
field_47 TEXT comment 'Column 48',
field_48 TEXT comment 'Column 49',
field_49 TEXT comment 'Column 50',
field_50 TEXT comment 'Column 51',
field_51 TEXT comment 'Column 52',
field_52 TEXT comment 'Column 53',
field_53 TEXT comment 'Column 54',
field_54 TEXT comment 'Column 55',
field_55 TEXT comment 'Column 56',
field_56 TEXT comment 'Column 57',
field_57 TEXT comment 'Column 58',
field_58 TEXT comment 'Column 59',
field_59 TEXT comment 'Column 60',
field_60 TEXT comment 'Column 61',
field_61 TEXT comment 'Column 62',
field_62 TEXT comment 'Column 63',
field_63 TEXT comment 'Column 64',
field_64 TEXT comment 'Column 65',
field_65 TEXT comment 'Column 66',
field_66 TEXT comment 'Column 67',
field_67 TEXT comment 'Column 68',
field_68 TEXT comment 'Column 69',
field_69 TEXT comment 'Column 70',
field_70 TEXT comment 'Column 71',
field_71 TEXT comment 'Column 72',
field_72 TEXT comment 'Column 73',
field_73 TEXT comment 'Column 74',
field_74 TEXT comment 'Column 75',
field_75 TEXT comment 'Column 76',
field_76 TEXT comment 'Column 77',
field_77 TEXT comment 'Column 78',
field_78 TEXT comment 'Column 79',
field_79 TEXT comment 'Column 80',
field_80 TEXT comment 'Column 81',
field_81 TEXT comment 'Column 82',
field_82 TEXT comment 'Column 83',
field_83 TEXT comment 'Column 84',
field_84 TEXT comment 'Column 85',
field_85 TEXT comment 'Column 86',
field_86 TEXT comment 'Column 87',
field_87 TEXT comment 'Column 88',
field_88 TEXT comment 'Column 89',
field_89 TEXT comment 'Column 90',
field_90 TEXT comment 'Column 91',
field_91 TEXT comment 'Column 92',
field_92 TEXT comment 'Column 93',
field_93 TEXT comment 'Column 94',
field_94 TEXT comment 'Column 95',
field_95 TEXT comment 'Column 96',
field_96 TEXT comment 'Column 97',
field_97 TEXT comment 'Column 98',
field_98 TEXT comment 'Column 99',
field_99 TEXT comment 'Column 100',
field_100 TEXT comment 'Column 101',
field_101 TEXT comment 'Column 102',
field_102 TEXT comment 'Column 103',
field_103 TEXT comment 'Column 104',
field_104 TEXT comment 'Column 105',
field_105 TEXT comment 'Column 106',
field_106 TEXT comment 'Column 107',
field_107 TEXT comment 'Column 108',
field_108 TEXT comment 'Column 109',
field_109 TEXT comment 'Column 110',
field_110 TEXT comment 'Column 111',
field_111 TEXT comment 'Column 112',
field_112 TEXT comment 'Column 113',
field_113 TEXT comment 'Column 114',
field_114 TEXT comment 'Column 115',
field_115 TEXT comment 'Column 116',
field_116 TEXT comment 'Column 117',
field_117 TEXT comment 'Column 118',
field_118 TEXT comment 'Column 119',
field_119 TEXT comment 'Column 120',
field_120 TEXT comment 'Column 121',
field_121 TEXT comment 'Column 122',
field_122 TEXT comment 'Column 123',
field_123 TEXT comment 'Column 124',
field_124 TEXT comment 'Column 125',
field_125 TEXT comment 'Column 126',
field_126 TEXT comment 'Column 127',
field_127 TEXT comment 'Column 128',
field_128 TEXT comment 'Column 129',
field_129 TEXT comment 'Column 130',
field_130 TEXT comment 'Column 131',
field_131 TEXT comment 'Column 132',
field_132 TEXT comment 'Column 133',
field_133 TEXT comment 'Column 134',
field_134 TEXT comment 'Column 135',
field_135 TEXT comment 'Column 136',
field_136 TEXT comment 'Column 137',
field_137 TEXT comment 'Column 138',
field_138 TEXT comment 'Column 139',
field_139 TEXT comment 'Column 140',
field_140 TEXT comment 'Column 141',
field_141 TEXT comment 'Column 142',
field_142 TEXT comment 'Column 143',
field_143 TEXT comment 'Column 144',
field_144 TEXT comment 'Column 145',
field_145 TEXT comment 'Column 146',
field_146 TEXT comment 'Column 147',
field_147 TEXT comment 'Column 148',
field_148 TEXT comment 'Column 149',
field_149 TEXT comment 'Column 150',
field_150 TEXT comment 'Column 151',
field_151 TEXT comment 'Column 152',
field_152 TEXT comment 'Column 153',
field_153 TEXT comment 'Column 154',
field_154 TEXT comment 'Column 155',
field_155 TEXT comment 'Column 156',
field_156 TEXT comment 'Column 157',
field_157 TEXT comment 'Column 158',
field_158 TEXT comment 'Column 159',
field_159 TEXT comment 'Column 160',
field_160 TEXT comment 'Column 161',
field_161 TEXT comment 'Column 162',
field_162 TEXT comment 'Column 163',
field_163 TEXT comment 'Column 164',
field_164 TEXT comment 'Column 165',
field_165 TEXT comment 'Column 166',
field_166 TEXT comment 'Column 167',
field_167 TEXT comment 'Column 168',
field_168 TEXT comment 'Column 169',
field_169 TEXT comment 'Column 170',
field_170 TEXT comment 'Column 171',
field_171 TEXT comment 'Column 172',
field_172 TEXT comment 'Column 173',
field_173 TEXT comment 'Column 174',
field_174 TEXT comment 'Column 175',
field_175 TEXT comment 'Column 176',
field_176 TEXT comment 'Column 177',
field_177 TEXT comment 'Column 178',
field_178 TEXT comment 'Column 179',
field_179 TEXT comment 'Column 180',
field_180 TEXT comment 'Column 181',
field_181 TEXT comment 'Column 182',
field_182 TEXT comment 'Column 183',
field_183 TEXT comment 'Column 184',
field_184 TEXT comment 'Column 185',
field_185 TEXT comment 'Column 186',
field_186 TEXT comment 'Column 187',
field_187 TEXT comment 'Column 188',
field_188 TEXT comment 'Column 189',
field_189 TEXT comment 'Column 190',
field_190 TEXT comment 'Column 191',
field_191 TEXT comment 'Column 192',
field_192 TEXT comment 'Column 193',
field_193 TEXT comment 'Column 194',
field_194 TEXT comment 'Column 195',
field_195 TEXT comment 'Column 196',
field_196 TEXT comment 'Column 197',
field_197 TEXT comment 'Column 198',
field_198 TEXT comment 'Column 199',
field_199 TEXT comment 'Column 200',
 primary key (entry_id),
 KEY date_modified (date_modified),
 KEY modified_by (modified_by),
 KEY archived (archived),
 KEY created_by (created_by),
 KEY mode (mode)) row_format=dynamic;
```

PS I'm aware that creating tables with 200 text columns is not a best practice from a data modeling standpoint. That's not what this question is about. I'm just trying to understand what the row limit is and how to calculate how many of those 8192 bytes my table is actually using.

Comment: Also interested in how VARCHARs would factor into this. I tried following the examples in  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-row-size-too-large-errors-with-innodb/ and got the same error on my Aurora instance.

Comment: _Aurora is not MySQL._ They have done an unknown number of changes to the InnoDB code, and they do not share information about what they've done. I think the only way to get an answer is to try incrementally fewer columns and discover the maximum number of columns by experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

"not a best practice ... not what this question is about" -- But that *is* what the answer is about.

Is the table `MyISAM` or `InnoDB`?  Assuming Innodb...

Meanwhile, here's some of the 'cause' for the limitation:

- Rows are stored in fixed-size (16KB) blocks in a "BTree".
- For various reasons, the maximum size of a single row needs to be slightly less than half of block, hence the "8126".
- To allow for "large" `TEXTs`, `BLOBs`, and even `VARCHARs`, there is a mechanism for storing such columns "off-record".  But the "pointer" to that takes some space -- namely 20-40 bytes, depending mostly on the `ROW_FORMAT` for the table.  Note -- some other row_format may avoid the problem you are facing.

Solutions:

- If these 200 columns are effectively an "array" of things, then they really should be moved to another table, connected to this one with a 1:many relationship.
- Often programmers simply say `TEXT` rather than figuring what is a realistic datatype.  Changing some of these columns (eg, to a smallish `VARCHAR`) *may* fix the problem.
- Compressing the data *in the client*, then storing into `BLOBs` or `BINARY(...)` *may* shrink things enough to fix it.
- Throwing some or all of the 200 items into a `JSON` string and declaring that a single column is likely to fix the problem (but may incur other issues).
- JSON plus client compression provides benefits of both.

Varchar? -- This is handled essentially the same as `TEXT`.

- If the entire row is too big, then *some* columns are moved to off_record storage.
- The candidates are `VARCHARs`, `TEXTs`, `BLOBs`, and `BINARYs`.
- Depending on the `ROW_FORMAT`, the cutoff for what gets moved is either 0 or 40 bytes.  There is, however, a few bytes of overhead left behind independent of the 0/20/40.  They possibly include `NULLness`, length, etc.
- That is, what remains in the on-record storage is more than 20 bytes for *any* row_format.  (Exception:  when the value is small enough, and for certain row_formats)

Other potential issues:

- I do not know if `GEOMETRY` is treated like `TEXT`.  If not, then might it be the cause for overflow?
- A few bytes can be saved by not using `BIGINT` if you don't need such huge values.  Each `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes (plus overhead).

Comment: FYI you're not allowed to create MyISAM tables on Aurora. [Certain MySQL features like the MyISAM storage engine are not available with Amazon Aurora.](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/). They modified the InnoDB storage engine to do distributed I/O, but they didn't modify other storage engines.